# ReSharper Keyboard Map

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I have been using ReSharper from  before Visual Studio added Refactor. Then, it was inevitable to use ReSharper. Now that Visual Studio includes a few Refactor functions, I get to do projects where the client can do without paying for the ReSharper licence.

My problem is that I am so used to the ReSharper keymap that switching to VS will affect my fluency and productivity. I am sure there would be some smart guy out there who has the same problem and, unlike me, has done something about it by creating a keymap macro.

I'd like to be able to type my ReSharper key combinations in Visual Studio and get the same refactor functionality (where supported).

Does anyone know?

Comment: Thanks but the two responses so far miss the essential point of the question. The question asks about a keymap not how to talk to managers (or stand up to my clients).

Answer (score 4):

You could buy a personal license of ReSharper and take it with you and use it and not worry about remapping. Plus, the personal license is much cheaper.

Also, you shouldn't let customers dictate what productivity software you can or cannot use. ReSharper is a no brainer. It pays for itself a few hours after install.

**Per Jim's Feedback:**

Exactly. Time IS money. The thing is, when programmers go and talk to managers to ask for a productivity tool, they fail to mention this fact. i've experienced the same thing. You ask, get denied, but then you should counter with the ROI argument (**R**eturn **O**n **I**nvestement) And the ROI on ReSharper is undeniable.

JetBrains did do an [ROI study on ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/resharper_benefits.pdf) (pdf link) and found that it pays for itself in days. That finding seems a little understated. My arguement is always that the break-even ROI for ReSharper is hours, not days.

Here's a snippet:

– ReSharper users report a 20–50% increase (with some individual gains of
up to 350%!) in their productivity when using ReSharper on top of Visual
Studio.
– If a developer hourly wage is $30–50, it can take ReSharper only 7 working
days to pay for itself.

btw. i don't work for JetBrains or own their stock. i just love their products.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you have customised but you can set keyboard shortcuts in the options 
Tools|options|keyboard there is a million different options.

If you are missing R# and don't want to pay look at [Code Rush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/Index.xml)

Comment: Wow. DevExpress ups the ante. CodeRush is definitely the next productivity plug-in i would consider if R# wasn't an option... for some odd reason. And free is a very nice price!